# JavaFX- Add/Remove Cell ObservableValue Listener from TableView

Tags: java, javafx

When I call `TableColumn#getCellObservableValue()`, will it return a new `ObservableValue` each time or a persisting, set one?

The reason I ask is I'm trying to add a `Listener` to every `ObservableValue` for each cell in a `TableView<T>`. I maintain each `ObservableValue<R>` in a given `TableColumn<T,R>` within a `HashMap<CellIdentity<R>,Listener>`.

The `CellIdentity<R>` attempts to use the `ObservableValue<R>`'s identity to lookup the `Listener`. That way if I use a `ListChangeListener` to detect when records are removed, I can unsubscribe the cell value listeners and prevent leaks.

```
private static final class CellIdentity<R> {
    private final ObservableValue<R> cellValue;

    CellIdentity(ObservableValue<R> cellValue) {
        this.cellValue = cellValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return this.cellValue == ((CellIdentity<?>)other).cellValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return System.identityHashCode(cellValue);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I take this `TableColumn#getCellObservableValue()`, wrap it inside a `CellIdentity<R>`, and put that and a `Listener` in a `HashMap`, I get nulls when I do get() later with same means I used to put() it. I am not able to retrieve the listeners.

How can I put a `Listenr` on each cell value in a `TableColumn`, and be able to retrieve it later to remove it?

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where it would be necessary to do something like this. Why not add a listener to the `TableCell` properties?

Comment: I was hoping I was overcomplicating it. What do you mean add a listener to the properties? Is that not what I am already doing?

Comment: I'm making a TableFilter control for the ControlsFX project. Here is where I am doing said operation. https://bitbucket.org/thomasnield/controlsfx/src/23734cf97755f38deefd9d3dd1e46e93741a764d/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/table/ColumnFilter.java?fileviewer=file-view-default#ColumnFilter.java-136:174

Comment: I figured it out. For a given `TableView<T>` with a `TableColumn<T,R>`, I tracked the identity of the `T` item rather than the `R` to track down the listener.